# how to locate a product inside supermarket via gps?

Tags: .net

My project is about supermarket automation and i need to add location inside the market via gps. I need to know how to add that gps coding into dotnet and how to give connection between laptop and smart phone for showing location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are libraries for interfacing with dedicated GPS devices to extract position:

[OpenGPS](http://opengps-net.sourceforge.net/)
[GPSLibrary](https://gpslibrary.codeplex.com/)
[DotSpatial](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/)

Depending on the device you're using for GPS and the sort of application you're connecting it to, one or more of these may be helpful to you.  Bear in mind that GPS indoors has some accuracy issues ([by design](http://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/performance/accuracy/)).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot locate something indoor using GPS. GPS is not for such high accuracy positioning. You can consider using a BLE beacon to implement indoor positioning.